# Java SQL matching

Tags: sql

Is there a syntax to match a variable exactly with a value in a particular column in a database and output whether there is the same value in the variable and in the column?

Comment: check javax.persistence? @Column is this what you want?

Comment: you mean you want to compare two values and see if they are equal? Is one of them a Java variable? If so you'd have to put that variable's value into a SQL statement (as a parameter) and then a simple `=` comparison in SQL will do the job

Comment: As @ADyson says am `=` will do the job. However, I feel like a simple example would clarify the ideas a lot.